# Maximise right circular cone volume with fixed surface area using inequalites

Tags: inequality, optimization, volume, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

This is a question inspired from [What is the relation between height and radius of base of a right circular cone when its surface area is given and volume is to be maximum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3133258/290189)

In the linked post, OP has solved for critical points for the problem and asks for verification, and he/she *doesn't* determine whether the critical points are local maximum.

Is there a way to solve this constrained [optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) problem using elementary [inequality](/questions/tagged/inequality), like [a.m.-g.m.-inequality](/questions/tagged/a.m.-g.m.-inequality) or [cauchy-schwarz-inequality](/questions/tagged/cauchy-schwarz-inequality)?

I've got the motivation since verification of local maximality is usually a second-order condition.  (i.e. involves second-derivatives)  The calculation can get messy in [multivariable-calculus](/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus).  An elementary [inequality](/questions/tagged/inequality) approach often gives more elegant and concise solution.

My attempt:

Keep the notations in the linked post.

- $r$: radius of base
- $h$: height of cone
- $V = \frac13\pi r^2h$: volume of cone
- $A = \pi r (r + \sqrt{r^2 + h^2})$: surface area of cone

Apply [a.m.-g.m.-inequality](/questions/tagged/a.m.-g.m.-inequality) on $rh$:
$$rh \le \frac{r^2+h^2}{2}.$$
$$V = \frac13\pi r^2h \le \frac13 \pi r \,\frac{r^2+h^2}{2} = \frac16 \pi r \left(\sqrt{r^2+h^2}\right)^2 \le \frac16 \pi r \left(r + \sqrt{r^2+h^2}\right)^2$$

Then I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$A=\pi r(r+\sqrt{r^2+h^2})$$ (the surface area). solving this formula for $h$ we get
$$h=\sqrt{\frac{A^2}{\pi^2 r^2}-\frac{2A}{\pi}}$$ plugging this in the formula for $V$
$$V=\frac{\pi}{3}\sqrt{\frac{A^2r^2}{\pi^2}-\frac{2A}{\pi}r^4}$$
Now we consider the radicand only which is equal to 
$$-\frac{2A}{\pi}\left(r^2-\frac{A}{4\pi}\right)^2+\frac{A^3}{8\pi^3}$$
So we have $$V=\frac{\pi}{3}\sqrt{\frac{A^3}{8\pi^3}-\frac{2A}{\pi}\left(r^2-\frac{A}{4\pi}\right)^2}$$
So we get $$V\le \frac{\pi}{3}\sqrt{\frac{A^3}{8\pi^3}}$$ and the equal sign holds if $$r^2=\frac{A}{4\pi}$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution!  It turns out to be a problem in quadratics.