# Minimize surface of cone with given volume without using derivatives

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given volume of cone equal to **V**, i need to minimize side surface area of given cone **without using derivatives**. Exactly i'm trying to use **AM-GM inequality.**

First of all i tried to do it like it was done here: [Maximise right circular cone volume with fixed surface area using inequalites](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133321)
, but got stucked - case in link is inverse:given *surface area* and we need to minimize *volume*. In addition in url OP works with **whole** surface of a cone(i need only side surface).
Here are my calculations:

Given $V; V_{cone} = \frac{1}{3}\pi R^2 h; A = \pi R l, A\rightarrow min. $ Since $l = \sqrt{h^2 + R^2} \;and\; h = \frac{3V}{\pi R^2}:$
$$l = \sqrt{ \frac{3V}{\pi R^2} + R^2} \Rightarrow $$ 
$$\Rightarrow A = \pi R \sqrt{ \frac{3V}{\pi R^2} +R^2} = \pi  \sqrt{ \frac{3V}{\pi} +R^4}$$
And then i got stucked. Any ideas how to solve it?

**UPD:**
I've also expressed $R$ on $h$ value. Then:
$R = \sqrt{\frac{3V}{\pi h} }, \; l = \sqrt{\frac{3V}{\pi h} + h^2 } \Rightarrow  $
$$\Rightarrow A = \pi \sqrt{\frac{3V}{\pi h} } \sqrt{\frac{3V}{\pi h} + h^2 }.$$
So, 
$$A = \pi \sqrt{\frac{9V^2}{\pi^2 h^2}  + \frac{3Vh}{\pi} } = \pi \sqrt{\frac{3V}{\pi}\Big(\frac{3V}{\pi h^2} +h \Big) }\rightarrow \min. $$
Hence $ \min is \; achieving \; \iff $ $h = -\frac{3V}{\pi h^2} \Rightarrow h^3 = -\frac{3V}{\pi}.$

**BUT** A is equal to zero in that case. Will it be the right solution?

Comment: No. It obviously is not zero since the volume, by assumption is positive. Furthermore, I don't think AM-GM helps here. Why don't you want to use infinitesimal analysis?

Comment: Cause now we're exploring block of exercises, which can be done using analysis, but also **can** be solved by using **inequalities** (as our teacher said)

Comment: I see. Have you tried to solve this using infinitesimal analysis? It's unlikely you could do this with any elementary inequality. You'd need to be well a experienced with inequalities to see something that might work straightaway.

Comment: Yes, i got solution with derivatives, then i got solution using inequality, i'll write it here as answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got this by myself already.

What we need is to express volume and side area on $R$ and $h$ values.

Then consider $A^2 = \pi^2 R^2 l^2.$

Because $l^2 = h^2 + R^2 :$
$$ A^2 = \pi^2 R^2 (h^2 +R^2) = \pi^2 R^2h^2 +\pi^2 R^4.$$

Express terms of equality on $V \Rightarrow$
$$\Rightarrow A^2 = \frac{9V^2}{h^2} + 3V\pi h.$$
Use AM-GM inequality: 
$$A^2 = 2 \frac{\frac{9V^2}{h^2} + 3V\pi h}{2} > 2\sqrt{27V^3 \pi \frac{1}{h} }.$$
This inequality will turn to equality $\iff \frac{9V^2}{h^2} = 3V\pi h \iff$
$$\iff h^3 = \frac{3V}{\pi} \Rightarrow h = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V}{\pi}}.$$
Now substitute it to area's formula and get answer: 
$$A_{min} = \pi R \sqrt{R^2+ \sqrt[3]{\Big(\frac{3V}{\pi}} \Big)^2  } = \sqrt{\pi^2 R^4 + \pi^{\frac{4}{3} } (3V)^{\frac{2}{3} }}.$$

Answer (score 0):

At first like inlink before we have derivative LM method:

$$ V= \dfrac{\pi R^2 h}{3};\, A= \pi R\sqrt {R^2+h^2};$$
We can remove constants by LM method
$$ V_1=  R^2 h\,;\, A_1=  R\sqrt {R^2+h^2};$$

$$ \dfrac{2Rh}{R^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt {R^2+h^2}+R^2/\sqrt {R^2+h^2}}{R\cdot \dfrac{2h}{2\sqrt {R^2+h^2}}}$$
which simplifies to
$$ h= \sqrt{2} R$$
and semi-vertical angle of cone
$$ \tan \alpha = \dfrac{R}{h}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

In terms of $R,$ the area and volume are

$$ A= \pi \sqrt 3 R^2;\,V= \dfrac{\pi \sqrt 2 R^3}{3} ;$$

are related by a non-dimensional number

$$ \dfrac{A^3}{R^2}=\dfrac{27 \pi \sqrt 3}{2}$$

Next the AM/GM method becomes relevant here.. to see this please give the most elementary situation that can be pulled into this problem as well.